# docker/wordpress/docker-compose permissions on bind mount volume trying to install themes and plugins

Tags: wordpress, docker, plugins, permissions, themes

I getting permission issues (or so it appears) on a bind mounted volume on a Mac that is preventing themes and plugins from being installed. I'm using docker-compose to create my container as follows.

```
  wordpress:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: wordpress
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
    restart: always
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: *****
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    volumes:
      - ./wp-content:/var/www/html/wp-content
```

The Container is created no problem. On my host mac the `wp-content` directory is created just fine and correctly populated. I can connect to my container (using `docker exec`) and see the mounted volume has default permissions of `drwxr-xr-x 1 1000 staff 160 Aug 14 23:04 wp-content` Whenever I try to install a theme or plugin it prompts for FTP credentials or if I add `define('FS_METHOD', 'direct')` to `wp-config.php` fails with "Could not create directory". I've also tried making permissions to `wp-config` from my host host wide open with `chmod -R 777 wp-content` and changing ownership from the container with `chown -r www-data:www-data wp-content`. Enabling debugging produces no `debug.log` in `wp-content`. I've also tried running apache as user 1000 using `user: "1000:1000"` and/or `environment: APACHE_RUN_USER/APACHE_RUN_GROUP` as per https://github.com/docker-library/wordpress/pull/249. Nothing seems to make any difference and I have no idea what to try next. I suspect this is something really simple but have exhausted everything I can find. Any tips or help would be greatly appreciated. I'm just trying to do some basic plugin development and would like to edit `wp-content` locally.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to make volume from the root directory of your wordpress install.
There is my docker-compose.yml file

```
version: '3.3'

services:
   db:
     image: mysql:5.7
     volumes:
       - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
     restart: always
     environment:
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: rootpassword
       MYSQL_DATABASE: dbname
       MYSQL_USER: dbuser
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: dbpassword

   wordpress:
     depends_on:
       - db
     image: wordpress:latest
     volumes:
       - wp_data:/var/www/html
     restart: always
     environment:
       WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
       WORDPRESS_DB_USER: dbuser
       WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: dbpassword
       WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: dbname

volumes:
    db_data: {}
    wp_data:
      driver: local
      driver_opts:
        type: none
        o: bind
        device: /var/www/html/
```